# Using chatGPT to create a web interface to output a latex document

Tags: python, html, chatbot, openai-api, chatgpt-api

**As a project i wanted to create a interface that when imputed with a engineering problem, the output would be an engineering calculation paper in latex that could be given directly to clients for example.
As i have a little coding experience i asked chatgpt to create the parts i need.
This was the code created.**

This will be a basic example, and won't actually compile the LaTeX or serve the PDF, but it should give you a good start. I'll use a very simple LaTeX document for the example.

`app.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import requests
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

app = Flask(__name__)

def ask_gpt(question):
    response = requests.post(
        'https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions',
        headers={
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer YOUR_OPENAI_API_KEY', # replace with your OpenAI API Key
        },
        json={
            'prompt': question,
            'max_tokens': 60,
        },
    )
    return response.json()['choices'][0]['text'].strip()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        question = request.form.get('question')
        answer = ask_gpt(question)

        # Load the jinja2 environment and render the LaTeX document
        env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
        template = env.get_template('template.tex')
        output = template.render(answer=answer)

        # Write the output to a .tex file
        with open('output.tex', 'w') as f:
            f.write(output)

        return 'Created LaTeX document'

    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`templates/home.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ask GPT</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="question">
        <input type="submit" value="Ask">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`template.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{{ answer }}
\end{document}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv4Yk.png)

In vsc i did all the steps required including adding my api key, how ever whehn clicking on the link generated the website was completely blank. I rechecked everything and it looked right, i even used a new api key so that was not the problem.

I tried changing the api key, repasting the code into vsc however the page was still blank.